# Theorem on continuity and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In the text *Mathematical Analysis, Second Edition* by Tom Apostol theorem 4.24 states:

Let $f:S\rightarrow T $ be function from the metric space $(S,d_{S})$ to another $(T,d_{T})$. Then $f$ is continuous on S, if and only if, for every closed set $Y$ in $T$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(Y)$ is closed in $S$.

However, wouldn't a constant function that maps all of an open set S to a single point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be a counterexample since the singleton {$x$} is closed.

Comment: $f^{-1}(\{x\})=S$ and $S$ is closed (respect to $S$) by the definition of closed set.

Comment: You have $f[S]=\{x\}$.  But $f^{-1} [\{x\}]$ may be larger than $S$.

Comment: @ForeverMozart how? There is nothing outside $S$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Oh right, well $S$ is closed in $S$... I guess this is what Mario posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is defined from $S$ to $T$, then for any topology on $S$ you have that $S$ is both open and closed. So $f^{-1}(\{x\})=S$, which is indeed closed.

Comment: Your right, because I just looked up that the set which defines the topology is both open and closed. I wish the text told me that in the first place!

Comment: @JamesFair Yes.  And sometimes sets other than $S$ and $\varnothing$ can be open and closed ("clopen").